# Allocating a specific sized array with a varying number and size of items

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, memory-management

I want to initialize memory for storage that will need to be capped at 2gb. Basically, I need to allocate 2gb memory then add items to the memory, and when adding an item, make sure it will not overflow the allocated memory. I was looking at `calloc()`, because the items should be stored in an array, but it only allows me to allocate the memory based of number of items and size of items. Because I do not have a specific number of items, or a specific size for items, this will not do. Is there someway I can allocate a 2gb array and have the number of items and the size of items dynamic>

Comment: Do the elements have to be stored in contiguous memory? How large are the elements? In any case, a normal C++ array (including std::vector) is out, because those only support a single type with a single, fixed size. It would also be helpful if you provided some info about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Well, the elements are of various size, but will be compressed, and yes the memory should be contiguous. Basically, a program would send strings that were compressed and encoded, and then store them in memory and look them up later. I am kinda trying to implement my own datastore from scratch :/

Comment: I don't see how that requires the elements to be stored contiguously. Up to now, my first reaction is to use a `list<string>` or any other similar container. You can wrap that container in a class that keeps track of the amount of used memory in order to cap it at some limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know the end size ahead of time, you could use a std::list or std::vector.  The storage for these data types will increase as more items are added.

Since you said you also don't know the size of each item, you could use some sort of structure with a pointer and size variable to store each individual item.